# Como formatar corretamente um valor monetário?

Tags: php, formatação, números

Possuo um valor que vem do formulário dessa maneira:

```
R$ 1.500,95
```

Preciso que ele fique assim:

```
R$ 1500,95
```

Como fazer ele ficar transformado que nem na 2ª maneira? **Preciso que ele fique totalmente igual à maneira a qual foi citada.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Faça a remoção do ponto e do R$.

```
<?php

$moeda = "R$ 1.500,95";

// Com str_replace (Remove a string 'R$ ' e '.'
$valor = str_replace( array('R$ ', '.'),  '', $moeda);
echo $valor; //1550,95

// Com preg_replace (Remove tudo que for diferente de dígito e vírgula)
$valor = preg_replace( '/([^\d,])/',  '', $moeda);
$valor = preg_replace('/[,]+/', ',', $valor); // Fix para caso seja passado mais de 1 ","
echo $valor; //1550,95

?>
```

Comment: Atualizei o código para fazer de duas formas, com preg_replace ou str_replace e também coloquei um comentário para ter uma compreensão melhor.

Comment: Utilizar o `\d,` você aceita vários `,`, ou seja o `1550,,,,,95` seria retornado exatamente como está, não seria removido os `,` adicionais.

Comment: @Inkeliz, certíssimo, adicionei a linha $valor = preg_replace('/[,]+/', ',', $valor) para comportar este caso, assim o valor ficará da forma correta.

Answer (score 3):

Uma outra solução seria remover somente manter os números inteiros e divido-los por 100.

```
$moeda = 'R$ 1.550,52';

$valor = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $moeda);    
$valor = bcdiv($valor, 100, 2);
$valor = strtr($valor, '.', ',');

echo $valor;
```

Resultado:

> 1550,52

Dessa forma, isso se tornaria:

```
string : 0e100 => 1,00
double : 0e100 => 0,00
string : 0x98 => 0,98
integer : 0x98 => 1,52
string : R$ 100.00 => 100,00
integer : 10000 => 100,00
double : 100.00 => 1,00
integer : 12345 => 123,45
string : 123.45 => 123,45
double : 123.45 => 123,45
string : 1a2b3c4d5e => 123,45
string : 123,45 => 123,45
string : R$ 123,45 => 123,45
string : 1 => 0,01
integer : 1 => 0,01

double : 9.0E+99 => 8999999999999999948859130765266355329578537025198862586562510896759102769772101980841694466750283776,00
integer : 9223372036854775807 => 92233720368547758,07
```

[Teste isto.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/76337e33d14a1d1ff4ebefa7a61ecdc66d763d49)

Esta função, do jeito que está, **tem "*problemas*" com float**, não recomendo que utilize para float/double. O float de `100.00` será `1,00` e `100.01` vai se tornar `100,01`, ou seja o `100.00` não vai para `100,00`, o que pode não ser esperado.

Obviamente é preciso que representação contenha os *centavos*, caso seja apenas `R$ 1.550` irá passar para `15,50`. Porém, informar `1.550,00` não terá problema, assim como `155000` ou até mesmo `1a550b00`.

*Caso encontre algum outro problema comentem, porque realmente não consigo imaginar algum, fora os mencionados.*

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar a função `preg_replace` ou `str_replace`, veja abaixo com `preg_replace`:

```
echo preg_replace('/^[0-9,]/', '', $valor);
// Saída: 1500,95
```

Comment: A saída desse comando sobre a string "1.500,95" resulta em ".500,95". Você está removendo tudo que começa com digitos de 0 a 9 ou vírgulo.